# Definite Integration without variables (?)

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

How would I go about solving the definite integral

$\int^{2\pi}_0 d\theta$ ?

At first, I assumed the integral of the angle between $0$ and $2\pi$, would just be the area of the circle, but since $r$ isn't in the integral, that's out the window. 
Is the answer then just $2\pi$ or, how does one solve this? Tried on a few CAS tools, neither of them works.
Cheers in advance

Comment: The integrand is 1, meaning the constant function 1. Thus, its primitive is theta

Comment: Not completely sure what you mean, what number does that make the integral return? Apparently the correct answer is given by the form $x*\pi$, where x is a constant between 0 and 99

Comment: @Drax, where did you see this "answer"? It sounds pretty implausible, even to a person who knows nothing about integration. Anyway, the given answer and the comment above are correct. The function you are integrating is $f(\theta)=1$. So the integral is the area of a rectangle with height $1$ and length $2\pi$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$\int_0^{2\pi}d\theta$ is short for $\int_0^{2\pi}1d\theta,$ and thus is simply

$$\int_0^{2\pi}1d\theta=[\theta]_0^{2\pi}=2\pi.$$